# GROUP BY multiple and different

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on an accordion like menu. I am trying to `GROUP BY` in multiple columns. I have researched but with no luck. I will break down my current structure:

In my database I have repeating `country` entries and `city` entries. The structure looks a little something like this (smaller example):

```
| ID  |  Country  |  City      |
________________________________

| 1   | Sweden    | Stockholm  |
| 2   | Sweden    | Stockholm  |
| 3   | Sweden    | Lund       |
| 4   | Sweden    | Lund       |
| 5   | Germany   | Berlin     |
| 6   | Germany   | Berlin     |
| 7   | Germany   | Hamburg    |
| 8   | Germany   | Hamburg    |
```

Using `GROUP BY` I can stop the repeating of same `VALUE` in my loop, here is the code I use for this:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT country FROM table GROUP BY country');
```

While this works perfectly. Now I want to grab `City` and place the values in my accordion drop down and at the same time not repeat those entries. Here is my current code (I'm using bootstrap collapse for the accordion effect):

```
<ul class="retailers-list"> // list
<?php  
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT country, city FROM retailers GROUP BY country');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
$country = $row['country']; 
$city = $row['city']; ?>

<li>
<a data-pjax="content" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?= $country ?>" href="retailers.php?country=<?= $country ?>">
<?= $country ?></a></li> //lists all countries not repeating

<div id="<?= $country ?>"  class="collapse in">
<a data-pjax="content" href="retailers.php?city=<?= $city ?>">
<?= $city ?></a><br> // listing only 1 city at a time
</div>
<? endwhile ?>              
</ul>
```

The Issue I am having is it only echo's one value, so it will only echo Stockholm, it won't echo Lund or any of the other values. I suppose this is caused because of GROUP BY country so is it possible to GROUP BY country and another value?

EDIT (Desired HTML output):

```
Sweden 
 > Stockholm
 > Lund
Germany
 > Berlin
 > Hamburg
```

Using DISTINCT the output look like this, which is not what I am looking for:

```
Sweden 
 > Stockholm
Sweden 
 > Lund
Germany
 > Berlin
Germany
 > Hamburg
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Can you show the desired HTML output ?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY is inappropriate (and most likely inefficient). Use the DISTINCT operator instead.

Comment: That is (or at least should be) a display issue. Issues of data display are best handled at the application level - e.g. a simple PHP loop (acting upon an ordered list).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add city in your GROUP BY:

```
SELECT country, city FROM retailers GROUP BY country, city
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you will need for each country a distinct list of associated cities.
If your result set is not to big in city:country ratio, you can use:

```
SELECT country, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT city) FROM retailers GROUP BY country
```

Echo the result to see how it works.

If the result set is big city:country ratio, You can simply either do

```
SELECT country, city FROM retailers GROUP BY country,city
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT country, city FROM retailers ORDER BY country,city
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, I did try this method but the issue is now in my edit.

Comment: use the group concat and do some PHP to convert it to what u need. That is the purpose of PHP.

Comment: The issue not know how I should convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm too dumb for PDO but a crude procedural approach might look like this...

```
SELECT * FROM cities2;
+---------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| city_id | city_name  | lat     | lon     | country |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 | New York   | 40.6700 | 73.9400 | US      |
|       2 | London     | 51.5072 |  0.1275 | UK      |
|       3 | Kodiak     | 45.0000 | 29.0000 | US      |
|       4 | Birmingham | 34.0000 | 45.0000 | US      |
|       5 | Birmingham | 52.2900 |  1.5400 | UK      |
+---------+------------+---------+---------+---------+

<?php
include('../testi.inc');
$query = "
SELECT DISTINCT country,city_name FROM cities2 ORDER BY country,city_name;
";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
 $country = '';

 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 if ($country == $rows['country']){
 echo  "  >".$rows['city_name']."<br>\n";
 } else {
 echo $rows['country']."<br>\n  >".$rows['city_name']."<br>\n";
$country = $rows['country'];
 }
 } // end of while loop
?>
```

Outputs:

```
UK<br>
  >Birmingham<br>
  >London<br>
US<br>
  >Birmingham<br>
  >Kodiak<br>
  >New York<br>
```

Comment: I been stuck on this one for 2 days, I see what you did here, but it seems to echo 2 results and I cant split results in collapse. Anything related to this is a start...

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.